# Limit number of input tags in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been searching for a jQuery auto-suggest tags (similar to the stackoverflow tags input) plugin which restricts the number of input tags (ie. does not allow to create  more than 5 tags for example?). If someone knows such plugin, or is [kind enough to modify this code](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/js/tag-it.js) to Limit the number of tags, I'll be really thankful.

Comment: +1 I am using the same plugin and looking to add the same functionality. I will get around to it eventually if no one offers a solution in the mean time

Comment: @stephen776 That will be great :) I think this plugin is very nice and should be easy to add a small function which counts the number of tags and limits it.

Comment: posted an answer. made a quick change to the tagIt plugin should be no problem to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok made a change to the Tag It plugin...

First open up the plugin js file and find the `is_new` function(towards the bottom of the file)...

replace the entire function with this:

```
    function is_new (value){
        var is_new = true;
        var count = 0;
        this.tag_input.parents("ul").children(".tagit-choice").each(function(i){
            count++;
            n = $(this).children("input").val();
            if (value == n || count >= options.maxTags) {
                is_new = false;
            }
        })
        return is_new;
    }
```

Notice I only added the `count` variable and modified the `if` statement in the loop to check if count is >= the option `maxTags`

Then when u call the plugin, set the maxTags option:

```
    $('#tagBox').tagit({
        availableTags: '../Tag/GetTags',
        maxTags: 5
    });
```

easy!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look though your code, but i'm assuming you have a convention for delimiting what tags are (space, comma, other) so you could track the number of dlimiters and then just not allow them to type after the 5th delimiter has been typed.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with the plugin the OP mentioned. There is no delimiter for the tags. It is basically an un ordered list with a textbox appended to the last list item for input. After text is entered, it appends the text to the list. In order to determine when a tag has been entered the plugin listens for enter or comma keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

[This one](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) looks good. Look at the `selectionLimit` property.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is using the **latest version of tag-it**, here is the solution : ) ENJOY!

```
_isNew: function(value) {
        var that = this;
        var isNew = true;
        //JAVI ADDED NEXT LINE
        var count = 0;
        this.tagList.children('.tagit-choice').each(function(i) {
            //JAVI ADDED NEXT LINE AND MODIFIED IF (ADDING SECOND CONDITION)
            count++;
            if (that._formatStr(value) == that._formatStr(that.tagLabel(this)) || count >= that.options.maxTags) {
                isNew = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return isNew;
    },
```